# jQuery put loading image on my tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `jQuery` tab and now I want to add simple loading image but got confused where to put and how to put?

Here is my JS code:

```
$('[data-toggle="tabajax"]').click(function(e)
{
    localStorage.setItem('lastTab', $(this).attr('href'));

    var $this = $(this),
        loadurl = $this.attr('href'),
        targ = $this.attr('data-target');

    $.get(loadurl, function(data) {
        $(targ).html(data);
    });

    $this.tab('show');
    return false;
});

var lastTab = localStorage.getItem('lastTab');
if(lastTab)
{
    $('[href="' + lastTab + '"]').tab('show').trigger('click');
}
else
{
    $('#userDetailsTab').trigger('click');
}
```

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs tabs-up" id="friends">
    <li><a href="userDetails" data-target="#userDetails" class="media_node active span" id="userDetailsTab" data-toggle="tabajax"> User Details </a></li>
    <li><a href="userGroups" data-target="#userDetails" class="media_node span" id="friends_list_tab" data-toggle="tabajax"> Group</a></li>
    <li><a href="userGroupAccess" data-target="#userDetails" class="media_node span" id="awaiting_request_tab" data-toggle="tabajax">Group Access</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="loading"><img src="assets/img/processing.gif"/></div>
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="userDetails"></div>
</div>
```

So how can I set this, if still loading show loading image and afer page loaded then hide the loading image.

Comment: You can, the first thing you do when loading your website, put up a big spinner sprite over the entire web page, then when your loading completes use jQuery to remove it.

Comment: @SimonHyll Please share me your trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the requested jQuery trick. Note that you'll have to modify it as appropriate, but something like this would make a huge spinner appear all over the web page and once your javascript functions have reached their end it will be removed, revealing your finished website.

```js
// Then call this function at the end of your loading sequence
//$("#wrapper").remove();
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3; /* Light grey */
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db; /* Blue */
    border-bottom: 16px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    width: 3cm;
    height: 3cm;
    position: relative;
    left: calc(50% - 1.5cm);
    top: calc(50% - 1.5cm);
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

#wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 99999999999999;
    top:0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>YOU CANT SEE ME</h1>
<div id="wrapper">
<div class="loader" id="mySpinner"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note that with some tinkering you can make this solution be placed over whatever part of your web page you want, you can also use jQuery to add the Spinner over an existing element to fill the parent, replacing only a part of your page with a spinner until you call the remove() function.